# require.js and r.js dependencies

Tags: javascript, optimization, backbone.js, requirejs

My app has been working fine but today I decided to give r.js a swirl.

Right now my tree(part of it) looks like

- index.html
- assets

  - js

    - require.js
    - r.js
    - main.js
    - components

      - underscore.js
      - jquery.js
      - backbone.js
      - jqueryuijs
    - models

      - election.js
    - collections

      - elections.js
    - views

      - app.js
      - election.js

in my index.html file I have 
`<script data-main="assets/js/main" src="assets/js/require.js"></script>`

and this is main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min',
        underscore: 'components/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'components/backbone/backbone-min',
        jqueryui: 'components/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min'
    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },

        'jqueryui': ['jquery']
    }

});

require(['views/app'], function(App) {

    var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'root',
            'year(/:year)': 'year'
        },

        root: function() {
            new App();
        },

        year: function(year) {
            new App({
                year: year
            });
        }
    });

    r = new router();
    Backbone.history.start({
        // pushState: true
    });
});
```

and in my modules I refer to my files like `assets/js/views/election.js` or `assets/js/models/election.js`

but when I run r.js with this build.js

```
({
    // baseUrl: "assets/",
    paths: {
        jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min',
        underscore: 'components/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: "components/backbone/backbone-min",
        jqueryui: 'components/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min'
    },
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js"
})
```

I get `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/alex/Dropbox/www/animated-elections/assets/js/assets/js/collections/elections.js'`. I get what it means by I don't understand why it is adding another `assets/js` to my paths.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `require.js` is supposed to go in the same folder as the main file, ie. next to the `assets` folder instead of inside it.

Answer (score 0):

r.js is inside your app directory, instead of being a sibling to it, as specified in the [example setup](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#setup).

I haven't tested this but r.js is probably assuming that any module calls should be relative to where it's located.

Comment: by changing the path of r.js and the paths in the files, I can get it to compile but it upon using the generated file, it says that the method `extend` is undefined, and when I log Backbone, it works, but underscore and jquery won't

Comment: I think you need to provide the `shim` config to the build options too. I found it was easier to pass main.js as [`mainConfigFile`](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L27) so that you don't have to define those settings twice.

Comment: ok so i just tried adding `mainConfigFile: 'main.js',` to build.js, and builds but it now says that `require` is undefined. I tried putting require.js in both the root (next to the file calling it in the first place) and in `assets/js`

Comment: You shouldn't have to move require.js, just r.js.

Comment: well require.js is back into assets/js/ and r.js is still at the root

Comment: Are you now loading the built file through the `data-main` attribute of the require.js script tag, or just including it in your page directly? (You should be doing the former)

Answer (score 0):

Add in the build.js file this codes.

```
baseUrl: ".",
paths: {
    jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min',
    underscore: 'components/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: "components/backbone/backbone-min",
    jqueryui: 'components/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min',
    'views/app': 'empty:',
    'views/election': 'empty:',
    //and so with others
},
name: "main",
out: "main-built.js"
```

Regards.-